# Jira service desk automation rule does not work

Tags: automation, jira, rule

I created an automation rule for service desk clients. If the client enters "Pass!" in the comment field, the incident status changes to investigate request.
This rule works in case of all invited service desk client expect one of them. We have 3 client accounts. Two works properly.
I tried his account, wtih the same result: entering the "Pass!" expression does not trigger the same rule, and the status of the incident remains provide information.
In the jira service desk log there are warnings , but the same for all users:

> /secure/CommentAssignIssue.jspa [execution.whenhandler.event.AllEventListenerEventWhenHandlerVisitor] Event when handler execution of com.atlassian.servicedesk.plugins.automation.servicedesk-automation-modules-plugin:servicedesk-commented-automation-rule-event-when-handler failed with error error.retrieving.project : 'error.retrieving.project'
>   Examine: vent when handler execution of com.atlassian.servicedesk.plugins.automation.servicedesk-automation-modules-plugin:servicedesk-commented-automation-rule-event-when-handler failed with error error.retrieving.project : 'error.retrieving.project'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

These are the areas I would check:

- Confirm that the automation rule has "User is a customer" set for the IF condition.  You can also try changing the run-as to project default (in rule options).
- Client login shows up in People -> Customers
- Client login shows up in Jira Administration -> User Management -> Groups -> Search "Jira-Users"